# My quarter reputation is more than my total reputation!

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

[image]

What is this? Is this some sort of wizardry? Or is the server bad at counting?

Jokes apart! Why is my quarter rep more than my total rep?

Comment: Asked and answered [on mother meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141628/263383)

Comment: Thanks! I now got the reason for this.